# Golang google client api, how to get the user information with `Userinfo` struct

Tags: go, google-oauth

I am currently building a backend Rest API with Golang to handle HTTP requests from a mobile application. One of the features that I am now implementing is a signup/login by using an external provider, e.g., Google, Apple, etc.

For Google, I've read this article on how to [authenticate with a backend server](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/backend-auth). The main idea is to send a token id to the backend via a POST endpoint and validate the content of the Token. Once the Token is validated, I can retrieve the user information from the backend and create an account (if it does not exist).

So far, with the [oath2](http://google.golang.org/api/oauth2/v2) Golang package, I can validate the Token like so:

```
func verifyIdToken(idToken string) error {
    ctx := context.Background()
    oauth2Service, err := oauth2.NewService(ctx, option.WithoutAuthentication())

    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    tokenInfoCall := oauth2Service.Tokeninfo()
    tokenInfoCall.IdToken(idToken)

    tokenInfo, err := tokenInfoCall.Do()

    if err != nil {
        e, _ := err.(*googleapi.Error)
        return e
    }
    fmt.Println(tokenInfo.Email)
    return nil
}
```

PLEASE NOTE: To obtain the token Id, I am using the [Oauth playground](https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/), and I set these scopes:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile
opened
```

After searching on [oauth2](https://pkg.go.dev/google.golang.org/api/oauth2/v2), I noticed a type `UserInfo` containing all the info I need. However, the `tokenInfo` object does not return all the information from the user, such as first name and last name. But, I'm having some difficulty on how to get UserInfo.

In short, I created a function called `getUserInfo` like so:

```
func getUserInfo(service *oauth2.Service) (*oauth2.Userinfo, error) {
    userInfoService := oauth2.NewUserinfoV2MeService(service)

    userInfo, err := userInfoService.Get().Do()

    if err != nil {
        e, _ := err.(*googleapi.Error)
        fmt.Println(e.Message)
        return nil, e
    }
    return userInfo, nil
}
```

NOTE: I called the `getUserInfo` within the `verifyIdToken`
`userInfo, err := getUserInfo(oauth2Service)`

However, I'm always getting this 401 error:

```
googleapi: Error 401: Request is missing required authentication credential. 
Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. 
See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project., 
unauthorized
```

With that, I'm not sure what to do.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have found the answer to your question for a long time, but I still leave my solution here.

The **UserinfoService** doesn't actually pass a token inside. To do this, you can use code like this:

```
import  "google.golang.org/api/googleapi"
```

```
    token := "ya29.a0Aa4xrXMAp..." 
    userInfo, err := userInfoService.Get().Do(googleapi.QueryParameter("access_token", token))
    if err != nil {
        e, _ := err.(*googleapi.Error)
        fmt.Println(e.Message)
        return nil, e
    }
```